# p:calendar uses 1930-2029 with MM/dd/yy date format

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

So I'm using a p:calendar with this date format: MM/dd/yy. If I choose any year until 2029 ( let's say 12/12/29 in my calendar input field) the value sent is the right one, but if I go for 2030 (12/12/30) it sends 1930 and it does for every year after 2030. Any idea why it behaves like that?

With a normal year format it works just fine, changing yearRange did not help. I'm using primefaces 5.3.

```
<p:calendar id="rechargeUntilDate" value="# 
{lotExpirationDateMB.rechargeUntil}" pattern="MM/dd/yy" 
maxlength="#{userDetailsMB.shortDateFormat.length()}" 
navigator="true" yearRange="c-10:c+100">
    <p:ajax update="rechargeUntilDateMessage rechargeUntilDate" 
    partialSubmit="true" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: Years have 4 digits.

Comment: In almost every platform today a 2 digit year representation is 1930-2029. You must use a 4 digit year representation if you want other years.

Comment: or see if you can 'configure' the default behaviour to move the window, but that is most likely not a jsf/primefaces thing but a pure java one. And 'effectively'  it is not a 'switch' from 2050 to 1950 but a 'two digit year format processed as 1930-2029'

Comment: And always try a newer version (7.0) is out already...